# jQuery Mobile a href data-ajax="false" does not let document.ready fire

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, document-ready

I have multiple pages (php files) in my mobile app. I use the same head for all of them: include('myhead.php'); at the start of all other files that contains mainly the CDN of jQuery and jQuery mobile. Last line of myhead.php is `</head><body>`

The php files have mixed content (php+html).
In one of the pages, I have a navbar with an ul inside with a hrefs where I call a php file with arguments. When I do that, my app opens a new browser and messes up my app by doing that.
 I tried adding to the **a href** the data-ajax="false" but that solves the browser thing only to leave me with another problem: document.ready does not fire in the destination page.

So I am in a pickle here. I have no idea how to proceed.
I need the document.ready to fire since I have a lot of elements in the destination page that need to be dynamically filled with data on pageshow (document.ready).

The code:
**page0.php**

```
<?php
 ...some code here session and mysql stuff
$myid = some number;
include('myhead.php');
?>

<script>
    // some jquery functions here
</script>
   .. page body content here
   .. and at the end I have the footer
<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar" class="ui-body-a">
  <ul>
     <li>other hrefs</li>
     <li><a href="page1.php?id1=<?php echo $myid?>" data-rel="external"</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the code for **page1.php**

```
<?php
    $mynewid = $_REQUEST['id1'];
    ...some code here
    include('myhead.php');
?>

<script>
   function func1(){
   // some processing here
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){
   // important processing here that dynamically populates controls on the page
   });
</script>

.. page body content here, controls that should be populated with data on document.ready
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to include the page2 **ALL** document.ready functions in the myhead.php in a script there? Would it be taken into consideration for my page? Would that mess up something?
Please advise.

As I said , I need the app to behave like a native app, and not to throw me out on new browser windows...

Comment: Generally speaking when using jQuery Mobile you should use their events, not document.ready. See here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: So, do you mean that if I replace document.ready with jQuery Mobile event, my issue will go away? Or is it just an observation...?

Comment: I assume that the problem is within `data-rel=external`. Links should work normally with ajax enabled but without external data rel. as mention by @NathanBouscal `.ready` isn't meant to be used with JQM, use `pageinit` instead for example.